# Renaming result categories in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the following query which outputs the number and percentage of members whose Salutation is Mr / Ms.

I want to rename the results to say 'Male' instead of 'Mr' and Female instead of 'Ms'.

It's probably a fairly simple CASE thing, but can't get it to work...

```
SELECT AspNetUsers.Salutation AS Sex, COUNT(AspNetUsers.Salutation) as Total, 
CAST(ROUND((COUNT(AspNetUsers.Salutation)* 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Member, AspNetUsers WHERE Member.AspNetUserId = AspNetUsers.Id)),1) AS NUMERIC(36,1)) AS Percentage
FROM Member, AspNetUsers
WHERE Member.AspNetUserId=AspNetUsers.Id
GROUP BY Salutation
```

Comment: The reason your attempt at using CASE isn't working is that you are missing the CASE statement.   Update your code to show your attempt, and we can correct where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely correct that it's a simple case expression that is needed, but you also need to group by the same case expression.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
      WHEN AspNetUsers.Salutation = 'Mr' THEN 'Male' 
      WHEN AspNetUsers.Salutation = 'Ms' THEN 'Female' 
      ELSE 'Other'  -- this is of course optional
    END AS Sex, 
    COUNT(AspNetUsers.Salutation) as Total, 
    CAST(ROUND((COUNT(AspNetUsers.Salutation)* 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Member JOIN AspNetUsers ON Member.AspNetUserId = AspNetUsers.Id)),1) AS NUMERIC(36,1)) AS Percentage
FROM Member
JOIN AspNetUsers ON Member.AspNetUserId = AspNetUsers.Id
GROUP BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN AspNetUsers.Salutation = 'Mr' THEN 'Male' 
    WHEN AspNetUsers.Salutation = 'Ms' THEN 'Female' 
    ELSE 'Other'   -- this is of course optional
  END;
```

The query could probably be improved by using a common table expression to not have to repeat the case expression, and a windowed count instead of a subquery, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Okay, so I'm make my newbie status somewhat obvious here, but how do I do that?!